# How to make d3-tip appear at all times?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart with `d3-tip`. Currently, the `d3-tip` only appears when I hover over any bar. How can I make them appear at all times, irrespective of the mouse event.

Comment: any reproducible example ? I think the way would be to create rect object

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.js"></script>
    <style>   
    .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      padding: 6px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
 
    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    .d3-tip:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      content: "\25BC";
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }
 
    /* Style northward tooltips specifically */
    .d3-tip.n:after {
      margin: -2px 0 0 0;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <svg width="640" height="500"></svg>
    <script>
    var radii = [10, 30, 20, 4, 60, 25, 45, 11, 12];
    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    
    
    // Setup the tool tip.  Note that this is just one example, and that many styling options are available.
    // See original documentation for more details on styling: http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/
    var tool_tip = d3.tip()
      .attr("class", "d3-tip")
      .offset([-8, 0])
      .html(function(d) { return "Radius: " + d; });
    svg.call(tool_tip);
    
    // Now render the SVG scene, connecting the tool tip to each circle.
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(radii);
    circles.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d; })
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return 50 + 50*i; })
      .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return 50 + 50*i; })
      .style("fill", "red")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .on('mouseover', tool_tip.show)
     // .on('mouseout', tool_tip.hide);
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your problem would have been more clear, if you have shown some of your implementation.
But as I understand, you have used d3.tip() to show tooltip over bar charts.

If you are calling d3-tip with DOM events like the following after d3.select on bar charts.

```
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

You can just simply not call the tip.hide.

See the attached code snippet of [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/davegotz/bd54b56723c154d25eedde6504d30ad7)

Comment: For this, you require to hover over the bar, for the tip to be visible. What i am trying to do is to show them as the load. No hovering

Comment: Well when I hover on other circles, it seems that the library only supports showing one tooltip at a time as the previous tip gets hide. You can append a div for each bar and show your tooltip data within it instead of using d3.tip() as it can only show one tip at a particular time.